# Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h Mac OS Sonoma

Tags: ruby, macos, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm using Mac OS Sonoma 14.2.1

ruby 2.6.5

imagemagick@6: stable 6.9.13-4

I'm trying to do
`gem install rmagick -v 2.16.0` 
catching it

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory: /Users/alenavolosina/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/gemsets/mosreg-base_4/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
/Users/alenavolosina/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby -I /Users/alenavolosina/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20240111-64476-m23n6.rb extconf.rb
checking for clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
checking for presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 6.9.0)... no
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/alenavolosina/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/alenavolosina/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/gemsets/mosreg-base_4/extensions/-darwin-23/2.6.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/alenavolosina/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/gemsets/mosreg-base_4/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/alenavolosina/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/gemsets/mosreg-base_4/extensions/-darwin-23/2.6.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

The command `find /usr/local /opt/homebrew -name "MagickWand.h"`
issues

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.13-4/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.1-26/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h
```

i tried it

```
brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig"
brew uninstall pkg-config && brew install pkg-config
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'
```

etc.

I tried all stackoverflow and more, tried reinstalling all dependent libraries, I also reinstalled Ruby 2.6.5, using rbenv, I'm at a dead end, please help me, good people

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `MagickWand.h` header file is missing.
You could check the `mkmf.log` file for more details but here are some things to try that are the usual culprits with issues like these:

1. Since you have already found `MagickWand.h` on your system, it's likely installed, but it might not be linked properly.

```
brew install imagemagick@6
brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

2. You've already set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH Environment Variable, but ensure that it's pointing to the correct version of ImageMagick

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig"
```

3. Sometimes, explicitly telling the gem where to find `MagickWand.h` can help

```
gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0' -- --with-magick-wand-include="/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/include/ImageMagick-6/wand"
```

If none of these work you could then try uninstalling and reinstalling imagemagick & rmagick.
Also make sure you don't have multiple versions installed. This can sometimes cause conflicts.
The last thing I can think of would be to try uninstall and reinstall ruby, and also ensure your macOS is up to date as it can sometimes cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

While all points from [8bithero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77805663/11721904) are correct, the bug is specific to ImageMagick 6.9.13-4 version and it is actually in MagickWand-config file(/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/bin/MagickWand-config):
line 9 is missing closing quotes

```
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="${exec_prefix}/lib/pkgconfig
```

so all you need is to change the line to:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="${exec_prefix}/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Took me a few days to find it